# conio.h not working in C

Tags: c

I'm having trouble with conio.h, I use Eclipse Standard but when I try to use clrscr, textcolor, textbackground, they all remain unresolved please advise me on alternatives or how I can get these to work. Thx.

Comment: What compiler are you using and on which platform?

Comment: I am amazed by how enduring `conio.h` is.

Answer (score 3):

[`conio.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) is DOS (or turbo-c) specific extension. It defines functions available in in that environment. Don't think its available in standard VC++ or gcc libraries now.

Comment: There is a `conio.h` included with Visual Studio's C runtime (verified on 11.0).  It doesn't have `clrscr`, `textcolor`, or `textbackground`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the .lib are available on the path.